# Integer Solutions To Linear Equation

Tags: number-theory, linear-algebra

$$a*q_1+b*q_2=c$$

$$a*q_3+b*q_4=f$$

$q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4$ rational numbers, $c,f$ integer

Given $q_1, q_2$ can you construct all solutions $(a,b)$ where $c,f$ is intenger

I made an edit since the original questions has too many solutions.

Comment: How did you convert it?

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic/fractions/Equivalent_fractions/v/finding-common-denominators